# Laravel 5.1 Eloquent orWhere Subquery

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am losing my head over this query. I really need assistance on this one:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM customers
WHERE (SELECT count(*) FROM customerEmails WHERE email = :email) > 0 
OR (SELECT count(*) FROM customerPhoneNumbers WHERE phoneNumber = :cellphone) > 0 
OR cellphone = :cellphone 
OR email = :email
```

I don't know if what should be eloquent code for this. TIA!

Comment: Are you using Relationship? and provide proper schema of required tables.

Comment: Your query isn't valid sql the way it's written. You won't be able to get laravel to generate that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Eloquent's [`whereHas`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) (just above that anchor a little) method to conditionally load `Customer`s depending on their relationships with other entities.  Assuming you have a model called `Customer`, you could try:

```
$count = Customer::whereHas('customerEmails', function ($query) use ($email){
    $query->where('email', $email);
})
->orWhereHas('customerPhoneNumbers', function ($query) use ($cellphone){
    $query->where('phoneNumber', $cellphone);
})
->orWhere('cellphone', $cellphone)
->orWhere('email', $email)
->count();
```